# How to change the lang="en-US" value of the HTML document?

Tags: html, localization, language

I have noticed that in the `<html>` tag on my WP site that the language is defined as US English.

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

I would like to change it to British English `en-GB` but I'm not sure of the best way.

I dug around and found `language_attributes()` in `general-template.php` which makes a call to `get_bloginfo('language')`. I could manually insert the value here but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

What is the proper way to change this value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value for that string is normally taken from the option `WPLANG` in your database table `$prefix_options`. You can set it in the backend under *Settings/General* (`wp-admin/options-general.php`) or per SQL.

There several ways to change that value per PHP:

1. Create a global variable `$locale` in your `wp-config.php`:

   ```
   $locale = 'en_GB';
   ```
2. Declare the constant `WPLANG` in your `wp-config.php`:

   ```
   define( 'WPLANG', 'en_GB' );
   ```

   This has been deprecated, but it'll still work.
3. Filter `locale`:

   ```
   add_filter( 'locale', function() {
       return 'en_GB';
   });
   ```

   This a very flexible way, because you can add more conditions to that function, for example check the current site ID in a multisite.

Answer (score 1):

As for recent version of WordPress 4+ the solution provided here is deprecated, please check my answer here for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37571439/1358670

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). Please add a solution.